# udisks eats up 9GB RAM in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome, ubuntu-gnome, udisks, memory-leak

Problem: udisks is taking more than 9GB memory in my openstack VM (keeps growing)

Note: more than 10 people have reported this so far.

**OS: Ubuntu 18.04
Gnome version: 3.28.4
udisk version: 2.7.6-3ubuntu0.2
libblockdev version: 2.7.6-3ubuntu0.2**

VM Spec: 16CPU - 40GB RAM

I Have seen similar bug was reported in Redhat - https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1684917

And was looking for patch for udisk2 and libblockdev as per the redhat ticket. But could find such version.

Is this already a known issue, is there already a patch for this? So many people have reported this bug for fedora and redhat but there is no fix available for Ubuntu yet